# Complements of subspaces and quotient spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I could use a hint on the following question

> Exhibit vector spaces $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ such that $A \oplus B = C \oplus D$, $A \cong C$, but $B \not\cong D$.

I have toyed around with a few trivial Euclidean spaces, but that isn't working.  I am thinking that the spaces have to be infinite dimensional because if all the spaces are finite dimensional, then the hypotheses imply
$$ \dim A + \dim B = \dim C + \dim D. $$
Then $\dim B = \dim D$ since $\dim A = \dim C$, and so $B \cong D$.  I only know of a couple of infinite dimensional vector spaces (e.g. sequence spaces, functions with finite support on a set $B$ of cardinality $\kappa$), but I'm not comfortable with their direct sums and don't see how to use them to solve the problem.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the question ask for Banach spaces?  Topological vector spaces?  What is the context?

Comment: Is it specifically asking for real vector spaces? Maybe you can do something over finite fields.

Comment: @BrianScholl Any v.s. as far as I know. This comes from a passing comment in Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra, in the beginning of the third chapter if I remember right.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, if $V$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{F}$-vector space, then $V\cong\mathbb{F}^{\dim V}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is any field. So you do have to go infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have an answer, now that I've thought hard about it for awhile.

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. Picking $A,C$ to be any two vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $\kappa$, and picking $B=\mathbb{R}$ and $D=\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we have $\dim A + \dim B = \kappa + 1 = \kappa = \kappa + 2 = \dim C + \dim D$. Since any two real vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic, $A\oplus B\cong C\oplus D$, but obviously $\mathbb{R}\not\cong \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

For $A$ and $C$, you should be able to pick whatever infinite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space you'd like. So, for example, $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\oplus \mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\oplus \mathbb{R}^{2}$, but $\mathbb{R}\not\cong \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got a copy of the book online, and I see what he means.

$A,B,C,D$ are subspaces of some vector space $V$.  Let $V = \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, that is, sequences $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$.  Let $A = \{(a_n):a_n = 0 \text{ if $n=1$}\}$, and let $C = \{(a_n):a_n = 0 \text{ if $n=1$ or $n = 2$}\}$.  Let $B = \{(a_n):a_n = 0 \text{ if $n \ne 1$}\}$, and $D = \{(a_n):a_n = 0 \text{ if $n \ne 1$ and $n\ne 2$}\}$.

Then $A$ and $C$ are isomorphic, $A\oplus B$ and $C\oplus D$ are isomorphic, but $B$ and $D$ are not.

Comment: thx. good explanation.